# POJO with list of POJO to JSON display size and index

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, pojo

So I've got those 2 Pojos:

```
public class RequestDisplayInfo {
    private int nombrePersonne;
    private String courrielOrganisateur;
    private RequestStatus statutDemande;
    private String salleAssigne;

    getters/setters.....
```

and

```
public class RequestsDisplayInfo {
    private List<RequestDisplayInfo> acceptees = new ArrayList<RequestDisplayInfo>();
    private List<RequestDisplayInfo> autres = new ArrayList<RequestDisplayInfo>();

    getters/setters.....
```

When I return the second class, I get something like this :

```
{
    - acceptees: [1]
            0:  {
                organizerEmail: "org"
                participants: 45
                requestStatus: "ACCEPTED"
                roomName: "plt-2828"
            }
    - autres: [2]
            -0:  {
                organizerEmail: "org"
                participants: 2
                requestStatus: "WAITING"
            }
            -1:  {
                organizerEmail: "org"
                participants: 3
                requestStatus: "WAITING"
            }
}
```

Here is how I return

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{email}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes({ "text/plain, text/html" })
    public RequestByEmailDisplay displayByEmail(@PathParam("email") String email) {
        List<Request> requests = requestService.displayByEmail(email);
        RequestByEmailDisplay requestByEmailDisplay = new RequestByEmailDisplay();
        requests.forEach(request -> {
            if (request.isAccepted()) {
                requestByEmailDisplay.getAcceptees().add(request.buildById());
            }
        });
        requests.forEach(request -> {
            if (!request.isAccepted()) {
                requestByEmailDisplay.getAutres().add(request.buildById());
            }
        });
        return requestByEmailDisplay;
    }
```

Which is what I want... except for the fact that it displays the size of the list and also the index of each element.

EDIT
I'm using Jersey/Jackson and directly returning it in my resources with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Does anyone know why and how to remove it?

Comment: How and where do you return it? What are you using to serialize your objects?

Comment: @mtyurt I'm using Jersey/Jackson and directly returning it in my resources with @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Comment: Please post your exact JSON response. The second code block does not contain valid JSON. This looks more like YAML.